# How to change list elements of specific indices to float in a list of lists (Python)?

Tags: python, list

I have a NumPy ndarray `array` that has been converted to a list of lists `array = [list(ele) for ele in array]`. I also have a list `indexes` that is entered into my function `to_float` as a parameter specifying the indices of elements within a list for all lists that must not be effected by the code in my function. The function has to convert all elements within all lists to `float` not specified by indices in `indexes`.

For example, my `array` (converted to lists) and `indexes` could be:

```
array = [['Hi', 'how', 'are', 'you', '4.65', '5.789', 'eat', '9.021'], ['its', 'not', 'why', 'you', '6.75', '5.89', 'how', '2.10'], 
['On', 'woah', 'right', 'on', '7.45', '9.99', 'teeth', '2.11']]
indexes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 6]
```

I now have to convert all elements in all my lists that are not indices specified in `indexes` to `float` values.

Desired output:

```
[['Hi', 'how', 'are', 'you', 4.65, 5.789, 'eat', 9.021], ['its', 'not', 'why', 'you', 6.75, 5.89, 'how', 2.10], 
['On', 'woah', 'right', 'on', 7.45, 9.99, 'teeth', 2.11]]
```

As you can see, elements with indices 4, 5, 7 in all lists were converted to `float` as their indices were not in `indexes`.

So how could I do this?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Write some code for me" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` and list comprehension:

```py
array = [
    ["Hi", "how", "are", "you", "4.65", "5.789", "eat", "9.021"],
    ["its", "not", "why", "you", "6.75", "5.89", "how", "2.10"],
    ["On", "woah", "right", "on", "7.45", "9.99", "teeth", "2.11"],
]
indexes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 6]

array = [
    [float(val) if i not in indexes else val for i, val in enumerate(subl)]
    for subl in array
]
print(array)
```

Prints:

```py
[['Hi', 'how', 'are', 'you', 4.65, 5.789, 'eat', 9.021], 
 ['its', 'not', 'why', 'you', 6.75, 5.89, 'how', 2.1], 
 ['On', 'woah', 'right', 'on', 7.45, 9.99, 'teeth', 2.11]]
```

---

Note: to speed up, you can convert `indexes` to `set`.

Comment: When I do `print(array[5][3].dtype)` my function is supposed to return `float64`, however it returns an error `builtins.AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'dtype'`. Is there anyway to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Never mind, it's all sorted. Thanks for the help!